# ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange() returns double single quote ' ' for each single quote ' in the sheet name

Tags: office-js, scriptlab

If sheet name is **my sheet's data**  the `m_address` and `m_addressLocal` properties of the returned range object will look like this
`"'my sheet''s data'!A1:B2"`

If used as-is in other API calls they will fail.

Workaround is string replace at a higher layer since can't alter the range.address property directly.

Comment: Let me pass this on to the dev team, and we'll get back to you.

Comment: thanks. It's not blocking me.  Just wanted to let you know about it.

Answer (score 2):

We investigated this, and I actually am not convinced we have a bug here.  The code below works.  When you say "if used as-is in other API calls they will fail", which API calls are you referring to?

```
try {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        const sheetName = `My sheet's data`;

        // Preemptively delete any previous incarnation of this worksheet, if any
        context.workbook.worksheets.getItemOrNullObject(sheetName).delete();

        const sheetAdded = context.workbook.worksheets.add(sheetName);
        const rangeB2 = sheetAdded.getRange("B2").load("address");

        await context.sync();
        console.log(rangeB2.address);

        const refetchedRange = sheetAdded.getRange(rangeB2.address);
        refetchedRange.format.fill.color = "orange";

        const differentFetchedRange = sheetAdded.getRange("'My sheet''s data'!B3");
        differentFetchedRange.format.fill.color = "purple";

        sheetAdded.activate();
    });
}
catch (error) {
    OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log(error);
}
```

You can try this snippet live in literally five clicks in the new Script Lab (https://aka.ms/getscriptlab). Simply install the Script Lab add-in (free), then choose "Import" in the navigation menu, and use the following GIST URL: https://gist.github.com/Zlatkovsky/bd5e82a3cf6da021cc1af13dddebba1b.  See [more info about importing snippets to Script Lab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab/blob/master/README.md#import).

Comment: Sorry, I guess I made assumptions about 'other APIs'. The specific API that breaks for me is this `context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("My sheet''s data").getRange("B3").select();` If you put this below your `sheetAdded.activate()` you will see it fail. The use case for me is to get the selected range in the workbook, show the sheet name (without extra quotes) and address to the user and let them jump to the range on click. Not sure why some APIs tolerate duplicate quotes and others don't. Here's a gist:(https://gist.github.com/jimbarrett33/99581000b3907fb1084e2b9b455c7c82). Nice add-in btw.

Comment: @JimBarrett, I would argue that the above is by design.  There is no sheet that has a double-tick-mark in it in the workbook, and so it fails.  There is a difference between seeing the tick marks when it's part of a larger `'Sheet Name'!A4` structure vs. when you do a `getItem`.

Comment: For your scenario, the right thing would be to query the "worksheet" property of the range and then load `worksheet.name`.